# Sync Safari bookmarks between computers

Tags: data-synchronization, safari, icloud, bookmarks

I've got a lot of bookmarks in Safari on my iMac. How do I get the same bookmarks show up in Safari on my MBA? Both using latest OS X with iCloud. I have checked Bookmarks in the iCloud settings, but no sync is taking place.

Answer (score -1):

Ahhh... I don't know what happened but somehow the bookmarks that I edited on the iMac just didn't reflect on the MBA at all. I am only using really the Bookmarks Bar and don't keep bookmarks anywhere else.

What I did:
Went into iCloud settings on the MBA. Switched Bookmarks syncing off. Then back on. It asked me if I wanted to sync and merge the local bookmarks with the ones in the cloud. I said yes. It synced, and I got double bookmarks everywhere (iMac and MBA). Then I just deleted the duplicates, and all seem synced and well on both devices. I sync with some iPhones, iPads too and it seems ok. The bookmarks there appear in the "Bookmarks Bar" subfolder.